# Perfect squares can't be primitive roots

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

This question was asked in my assignment on number theory and I am struck on this.

Question: Prove that perfect squares can't be primitive roots if p>2.

Attempt: let a is a perfect square and on the converse it is a primitive  root. then there exists an $0\leq x \leq p-1$ such that $x^2 \equiv a(mod p)$. also, $x^2 \equiv b^2 (mod p)$=> $(x^2-b^2) \equiv 0(mod p)$ which implies that $(x-b) \times (x+b)\equiv 0 (mod p)$. p being prime implies that either $x\equiv b (mod p)$ or $x \equiv -b (mod p)$. But, I am not able to move forward from this.

Can you please give a few hints?

Thanks!

Comment: Use \pmod{p} to get the correct typesetting.

Comment: A perfect square is a square modulo $p$. If it were also a primitive root, then it would be congruent to an even power of itself, which means it has odd order modulo $p$.

Comment: @Yoja FYI, a basically duplicate post is [Show that if $a$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$, then $a$ is not a primitive root mod $p$.](/q/2257022/602049).